# Gradle not pulling down new dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble updating my Gradle project with new packages. In IntelliJ I checked `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repositories`.
It shows the following repos:

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
/Users/paulcarron/.m2/repository
```

I tried updating them but now both show the following error:
[image]

Could this be the reason my project isn't updating and if so how do I resolve this?

Comment: if you are using Gradle, you should not be tied to the IntelliJ settings. does you command line work ? if it works there it should work in IntelliJ. are there any access issues to repo1.maven.org. ?

Comment: In regards to the Maven repository error: you can see the reson of the error when you hover over it. The full error is displayed i idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action). As for the Gradle problem - include exact error you are getting and when. Also - can you build by Gradle from the command line: `gradle build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Gradle tools window I then right clicked the project and selected `Refresh Gradle Dependencies` it was pulled down.